# TypeError: {'name:busi,group:1'} is not JSON serializable when constructing a json in python by scratch

Tags: python, json, list, d3.js

How can we dynamically create a json file in python by using the csv data or the data provided as a list

data.csv looks like this

```
busi,biz
thank,pump
thank,such
thank,merri
```

which shows the links/edges between nodes in a graph.

I am trying to construct a json of nodes and arrays but I am getting json serialisation error.

```
nodes = []
nodes_dict = {}
counter = 0
edges = open(edges_file)
    for line in edges:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        source =  line.split(",")[0]
        target = line.split(",")[1]
        if source not in nodes_dict:
            node_arr = {"name:" + source  + "," + "group:1"}
            nodes.append(node_arr)
            nodes_dict[source] = counter
            counter += 1

        if target not in nodes_dict:
            node_arr = {"name:"+ target + "," + "group:1"}
            nodes.append(node_arr)
            nodes_dict[target] = counter
            counter += 1
 json.dumps(nodes,outputfile)
```

But I am getting this error

> TypeError: {'name:busi,group:1'} is not JSON serializable

My desired output

```
 "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
        {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
{"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}],
"links":
            [{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},{"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
                {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},{"source":3,"target":2,"value":6}}
}
```

Comment: You are constructing a `set` (which is not JSON serializable) not a `dict`. See the documentation on those two types for details.

Comment: Are you thinking that ` {'name:busi,group:1'}` is a dictionary? It looks like one... but it's actually a set. Which can't be serialized as json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building your dict wrong.

Try something like this

```
nodes = []
nodes_dict = {}
counter = 0
edges = open(edges_file)
    for line in edges:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        source =  line.split(",")[0]
        target = line.split(",")[1]
        if source not in nodes_dict:
            node_arr = dict(
                name=source,
                group=1
            )
            nodes.append(node_arr)
            nodes_dict[source] = counter
            counter += 1

        if target not in nodes_dict:
            node_arr = dict(
                name=target,
                group=1
            )
            nodes.append(node_arr)
            nodes_dict[target] = counter
            counter += 1
 json.dumps(nodes,outputfile)
```